# Passing arguments from a text file to Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

everyone. I've recently started playing around with (Common) Lisp and right now I'm trying to figure out how to use it with the content of some text files. I have test.lisp:

```
(defun double (x)
    (* 2 x))

(defun main (arg)
    (print (double arg))
(quit))
```

and I compiled it with

> clisp -c -q test.lisp

and ran it from the Linux terminal with

> clisp -q -q -x '(progn (load "test") (main 10) (quit))'

which gave me the output "20". So that works fine, but is there a way I can pass the 10 in from a text file(testing.txt) somewhere? Or maybe even from the output of some program written in C, for example? I know passing just the one argument is trivial, but I'll get to multiple arguments once I know how to pass in a single argument at least. The command I'm using to run it actually just looks like I'm throwing the three commands/functions into the REPL, so maybe there's another way to run the file that I'm missing?

Maybe this is a pointless question, but if there's a way to do something like this, I'd appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, let's start with what your _end goal_ is. Is it to get the output of a C program? Or just the contents of a file? Or something else entirely? The _why_ makes a huge difference, and it's important to articulate in in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it was so important. My goal here is just to pass in values from a text file as arguments for, in this case, my 'main' function. Like I said, it may be a pointless question because I don't necessarily have an end goal, I'm just curious. For the sake of finding an answer, lets say my goal is to run the output of a C or Java program through my Lisp function 'main'.

Comment: This shouldn't be difficult. Have you looked at the file management functions for CL (*e.g.*, http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/files-and-file-io.html)?

Comment: @nandom Okay, so it sounds like curiosity is your end goal. That's fine. The reason I ask for this is to prevent an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/13): if there's an actual problem you're trying to solve, it's best to know ahead of time what that is. :-) But as I said, curiosity is fine too.

Comment: @lurker Oh, you're right. That's a good resource, thank you :) I guess I'm just used to using cat to pass in arguments haha. I guess I can work with that though, thank you. My bad.

Comment: @nandom Ive got a question because this is such an unusual request. How do you usually develop lisp, what tools (if any) do you use? I ask because the code/compile/run cycle for lisp is very different from many languages, and for standard development you certainly don't want to code lisp in the pattern you describe above. Of course if this is just for curiosity then have fun!

Answer (score 3):

Use `with-open-file` to open a file (it opens a file and automatically closes it when execution leaves its scope).

If you have a text file like this:

```
13
19
```

you can load and add these numbers like this:

```
(with-open-file (in #p"foo" :direction :input)
  (let ((numbers (loop :for line := (read-line in nil)
                       :while line
                       :collect (parse-integer line))))
    (reduce #'+ numbers)))
```